# Pass initialize options to Backbone Model through collection fetch method

Tags: backbone.js, collections, initialization

I have a Backbone Model which I want to initialize with some options:

```
 Payment.Payment = Backbone.Model.extend

    initialize: (attributes, options) ->
        @user = options.user
```

These Payments are fetched from the server through a Payment Collection

```
# Collections: Payments
Payment.Payments = Backbone.Collection.extend
    model: Payment.Payment
    url: 'api/payments'

    initialize: (models, options) ->
        @user = if options?.user then options.user else app.user
```

When I try to fetch a set of payments from the server, however, I can't find a way to pass the user option to each of the Payment models:

```
payments = new Payment.Payments
payments.fetch()
```

I've tried passing in a user option as a parameter to the fetch call, but that doesn't work. How then can I instantiate all the payment models fetched from the server with the user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have tried the simplest:

```
payments.fetch user: payments.user
// have no idea what I'm doing
```

In JS ^^:

```
payments.fetch({user: payments.user});
```

The options you pass fetch will be given to the models.

Comment: Thanks - I'd actually tried this and it wasn't working for another reason, but you're right, this is the right way.